# Print lines of csv file that contain specified keyword

Tags: python, csv, if-statement, printing, lines

I'm new to Python but I would like to do some data analysis on some csv files. I'd like to print lines from a csv file that only include some keywords. I use the first block to print all valid lines. From these lines I would like to print the ones including keywords. Thanks for your help.

```
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
invalids = 0
valids = 0
for f in ['1.csv']:
    reader = csv.reader(open(f, 'rU'), delimiter='|', quotechar='\\')
    for row in reader:
        try:
            print row[2] 
            valids += 1
        except:
            invalids += 1
print 'parsed %s records. ignored %s' % (valids, invalids)
```

With keywords:

```
    for w in ['ford', 'hyundai','honda', 'jeep', 'maserati','audi','jaguar', 'volkswagen','chevrolet','chrysler']:
```

I guess I need to filter my top code with an if statement, but I've been struggling with this for hours and can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: In which columns would you like to search the keywords for?

Comment: The file is a CSV with single column (so the first one). Thanks

Comment: So you don't need the `csv` module at all.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you have tried so far. This will show that you have actually done some work and draw more attention to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct. All you need to do is filter the lines with an if statement, checking if each field matches a keyword. Here is how you do it (I've also made some improvement to your code and explained them in the comments.):

```
# First, create a set of the keywords. Sets are faster than a list for
# checking if they contain an element. The curly brackets create a set.
keywords = {'ford', 'hyundai','honda', 'jeep', 'maserati','audi','jaguar',
            'volkswagen','chevrolet','chrysler'}
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
invalids = 0
valids = 0
for filename in ['1.csv']:
    # The with statement in Python makes sure that your file is properly closed
    # (automatically) when an error occurs. This is a common idiom.
    # In addition, CSV files should be opened only in 'rb' mode.
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', quotechar='\\')
        for row in reader:
            try:
                print row[2] 
                valids += 1
            # Don't use bare except clauses. It will catch
            # exceptions you don't want or intend to catch.
            except IndexError:
                invalids += 1
            # The filtering is done here.
            for field in row:
                if field in keywords:
                    print row
                    break
# Prefer the str.format() method over the old style string formatting.
print 'parsed {0} records. ignored {1}'.format(valids, invalids)
```